# ¿Cómo presentar los coeficientes de una variable explicativa cualitativa de mas de 2 categorías en un modelo GLM?

Tags: r, glm

esta es mi primera pregunta ya que me estoy iniciando en el lenguaje R.
Trato de generar un modelo logit y probit en el cual las variables explicativas de mas de dos categorias presenten su coeficiente.
Inicio importando un dataset en formato stata mediante:

```
library(haven)
```

> base_1 <- read_dta("Desktop/juan/R/final.dta")

Anexo la visualizacion de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El modelo lo planteo como:

```
modelo1=glm(resiliente~vandalismo+absentismo+ubicacion+posee_libros+
        Solo_leo_si_tengo+Leer_es_aburrido+sexo+Problema_con_palabras+
      apoyo_padres+El_docente_dice_cosas_interesant,family =binomial(),data = base_1)
```

y obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera obtener una salida similar a la presentada en stata donde se presentan los coeficientes de las categorias de referencia así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Esto sucede porque R está leyendo tus variables categóricas como numéricas. Entonces lo que tienes que hacer es convertir a `factor` tus variables.

Como estás usando la función `read_dta()` no te está cargando la etiqueta de las categorías. Te sugiero que lo cargues con la función `read.dta()` del paquete `foreign`.

```
library(foreign)
base_1 <- read.dta("Desktop/juan/R/final.dta")
```

Y ya luego vuelves aplicar tu modelo.

Ahora si deseas convertir en factor manualmente tienes que usar la función `factor()`. Por ejemplo:

```
base1$vandalismo<-factor(base1$vandalismo, levels=1:3, 
                         labels=c("No es un problema","Problema menor","problema moderado"))
```

En `levels=1:3` le indico el número que toma cada categoría y en `labels` le indico las etiquetas que a cada número le corresponde.

Una vez que terminas de transformar todas tus variables cualitativas corres tu modelo. pero como te mencioné anteriormente, te resultará suficiente si lees tu tabla de datos con la función `read.dta()`